# Docker entry point cannot find directory/file

Tags: c, docker, makefile, dockerfile

I'm trying to run a simple Linux program that interfaces with `/dev/net/tun` in a Docker container. My project consists of three files, `ctuna.c`, the source file for my program which contains a call to `open("/dev/net/tun", ...)`, a `Makefile` and the following `Dockerfile` which builds and runs my program:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest AS base

RUN set -ex; \
    apt-get update; \
    apt-get install -y build-essential libcap-dev

FROM base as build

RUN set -ex; \
    mkdir -p /usr/src

COPY . /usr/src/ctuna

RUN set -ex; \
    cd /usr/src/ctuna; \
    make; \
    make install

FROM base as run

COPY --from=build /usr/local/bin /usr/local/bin

RUN set -ex; \
    mkdir -p /dev/net; \
    mknod /dev/net/tun c 10 200

ENTRYPOINT ["ctuna"]
```

Building the image works but when I run it, `ctuna` cannot find `/dev/net/tun`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: please add your makefile, it is unclear why using the `ctuna` command would work. also please add a listing of your build context

Comment: A Docker container runs in an isolated environment, and Docker provides the network environment.  You'll need to disable some of Docker's controls to access network devices.  This sort of process might be better run from the host, outside a container.